# Juju and problem with subcontainers deployment on LXC

Tags: juju, lxc, openstack-autopilot

I am trying to deploy OpenStack with Juju and Autopilot but I have a big problem and I cannot figure out what to do.

Basically, I have a Juju local environment with LXC and it seems to work well if I write commands like:

```
juju deploy wordpress
```

Juju correctly creates a LXC container and the service works also.

Nevertheless, if I try to do:

```
juju deploy wordpress --to lxc:0
```

which is exactly what the Autopilot tries to launch, I get this error:

```
machines:
  "0":
    agent-state: started
    agent-version: 1.21.1.1
    dns-name: localhost
    instance-id: localhost
    series: trusty
    containers:
      0/lxc/0:
        agent-state-info: 'container failed to start: container failed to start'
        instance-id: pending
        series: trusty
    state-server-member-status: has-vote
```

I suppose I have some kind of incompatibility with LXC subcontainers and I don't know how to solve the problem. I am using Ubuntu 14.04 LST.

Comment: I should add some clues from my recent investigation: running juju from single local machine states this on 0/lxc/0 container

    failed to mount '/var/log/juju'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [OpenStack Autopilot](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/cloud/install-ubuntu-openstack) will (under the hood) use the MAAS provider for Juju, you can't use the Landscape OpenStack Autopilot with a local Juju environment.

That said, you can use the [Ubuntu OpenStack Installer's single installer mode](http://ubuntu-cloud-installer.readthedocs.org/en/latest/single-installer.guide.html) to limit your hardware footprint to one machine. It will install OpenStack in LXC containers on your machine.

Your error from attempting to nest LXCs is solved by following the steps in the [Server Guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/lxc.html#lxc-nesting), note that using nested LXCs this way to deploy OpenStack is unsupported, please follow the single installer path if you can't have enough hardware to deploy OpenStack in the Autopilot.